# Querying firebase database to retrieve user name

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on firebase for the first time. I am confused in querying the database. I have two objects on the database, one is the `Auth` and second one is the `Chats`. In `Auths` I have number of `UID`(user id) nodes, each of these nodes have their respective `username`. What I am trying to do is, I want to query that `Auth` object and get all the usernames which is equal to the one I take from a user through input box. In my sql it will be simple as `SELECT * FROM auth WHERE username = userInputValue`. I need same query like this, Below is what I have done so far.

```js
var _firbaseDB = firebase.database(),
    _firebaseAuthRef = _firbaseDB.ref("Auth/");

$("body").on("submit",".search-from",function(e){
    
    e.preventDefault();
    var ev = e.target,
       _allUsers = $(ev).serializeArray()
       _user = _allUsers[0].value;


    _firebaseAuthRef.equalTo(_user).on("child_added",function(res){
      console.log(res.val());
    })   


})
```

[image: This is the Object Structure of AUTH]

Comment: Try this: `_firebaseAuthRef.orderByChild("n").equalTo(_user).on("child_added",function(res){
      console.log(res.val());
    })`

Comment: Great, it worked mate :) please make it the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. What's missing is that you need to specify which attribute you're querying on:

```
_firebaseAuthRef.orderByChild("n").equalTo(_user).on("child_‌​added",function(res)‌​{
 console.log(res.val());
 })
```

More info on the [Firebase Database Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data).